# How can I populate a UIPickerView column with multiple arrays depending on what the row in first column is?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am looking to make a bus related app. I have a UIPickerView with two columns. The first column will list all of the buses. The second column will list all of the stops that correspond to the bus that is selected in the first column. It would not be wise to list every single stop no matter what bus is selected in the first column so I split up the stops into arrays (each bus corresponds to an array of stops).

So far I have gotten it to work with just one array of stops (stopsArray002) however I am not sure how to make it so it automatically populates the second column if a different bus is selected in the first column (the bus selection column).

At the moment I have three different stop arrays, each that should correspond to the bus number. I wish to set the bus label to corresponding bus and stop label to corresponding stop. As of now, my bus label displays what I want it to (the bus that is selected) and the stop label displays what 002 stop it is. The following is my code.

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *busLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *stopLabel;
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *busPicker;

    NSArray *busArray;

    // STOP ARRAYS
    NSArray *stopsArray002;
    NSArray *stopsArray006;
    NSArray *stopsArray007;
}

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    busArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                @"BUS",
                @"002",
                @"006",
                @"007",
                @"012",
                @"014",
                @"017",
                @"101",
                @"102",
                @"103",
                @"141",
                @"142",
                @"147",
                @"181",
                @"182",
                @"189",
                @"241",
                @"300",
                @"301",
                @"302",
                @"303",
                @"304",
                @"401",
                @"402",
                @"403",
                @"500",
                @"501",
                @"502",
                @"503",
                @"640",
                @"701",
                @"702",
                @"703",
                @"704",
                @"819",
                @"940",
                nil];

    stopsArray002 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     @"STOP",
                     @"002 1st",
                     @"002 2nd",
                     @"002 3rd",
                     @"002 4th",
                     @"002 5th",
                     @"002 6th",
                     @"002 7th",
                     nil];

    stopsArray006 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     @"STOP",
                     @"006 1st",
                     @"006 2nd",
                     @"006 3rd",
                     @"006 4th",
                     nil];

    stopsArray007 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     @"STOP",
                     @"006 1st",
                     @"006 2nd",
                     nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0) // bus column
        return [busArray count];

    else // stop column
    {
        return [stopsArray002 count];
    }
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0)
        busLabel.text = [busArray objectAtIndex:row];

    else
        stopLabel.text = [stopsArray002 objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0)
        return [busArray objectAtIndex:row];

    else
        return [stopsArray002 objectAtIndex:row];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a dictionary here, add the arrays to the dictionary and make the key the value for your bus.

So when you want an array for a particular bus then you would get it like this

```
NSMutableDictionary busStops
[busStops setObject:stopArray007 forKey:@"007"]
[busStops setObject:stopArray002 forKey:@"002"]

[busStops objectForKey:@"002"] //Will return array
[busStops allKeys] //Will return all your keys as an array you can use for first picker
```

Comment: I do not really understand how to implement this into my problem. I think I would understand if I first understood the question at hand. Thank you.

Comment: I have figured out my problem. Now I just need to figure out how can I set a smaller font for BOTH columns of my uipickerview?

Comment: You can use pickerView:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent: to set the font that you want. Although if I were you I'd learn how to use pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView: as it will give you better control of how the content is displayed on your pickerview